# How to create a IAM role which will enable users to create a s3 bucket encrypted

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

i have to make sure users who create S3 buckets in AWS console they have to encrypt it. if they do not they are not allowed to create S3 bucket.
How do we achieve this.

Comment: what encryption are you talking about ? do you mean object encryption when they're being uploaded ? if so, you can have bucket policy restriction on server-side-encryption or have the default encryption enabled on the bucket.

Comment: i am  not referring to object encryption. when we create a new bucket we have an option to select encryption either default encyption or AWS 256 or AWS KMS

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

The reason is that the [PUT Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUT.html) API call does not specify the encryption parameter.

Instead, it can be set via [PUT Bucket encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTencryption.html).

Since these are different API calls, it is not possible to create a policy that enforces encryption on bucket creation.

Instead, you can **enforce encryption on creation of objects**. See: [How to Prevent Uploads of Unencrypted Objects to Amazon S3 | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prevent-uploads-of-unencrypted-objects-to-amazon-s3/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the make sure the S3 default encryption option is enabled. You can accomplish this with AWS Config.

You want to create AWS Config rule.  This is how AWS Config works:

1. Create an S3 Bucket
2. The AWS Config rule runs shortly after bucket creation.  If default encryption is set, compliance passes, all is happy.
3. If default encryption is not set then the resource is in non-compliance.
4. If there is a remediation action then it is run.  In this case
   AWS-EnableS3BucketEncryption lambda is run which will enable default
   encryption for you.
5. Bucket state changed, and the Config rule is triggered again this
   time setting the status to compliance.

Setup Steps:

1. Create a new AWS Config rule.  [Link for us-east-1](https://console.aws.amazon.com/config/home?region=us-east-1#/rules/view)
2. Click "Add Rule"
3. In the "Filter by rule name" field enter
   "s3-bucket-server-side-encryption-enabled"
4. Now Scroll down to the "Remediation action" and select
   "AWS-EnableS3BucketEncryption"
5. Save it

That should do it. Happy encryption.

Comment: Hello WaltDe i tried the above steps and i think AWS config is to monitor to see certain policy are meet for a aws resources . if not it will show non compliance. this will not achive what we need. i was still able to create a bucket . any other suggestion?

Comment: what i also observed is we can re mediate the s3 buckets with the policy mentioned above. no need of going to that bucket and manually enabling the encryption. this is a very good feature.

Comment: @AjayR Config doesn't prevent you from creating a Bucket without encryption.  What is does is report on Buckets without encryption and in this case will enable encryption through remediation.   It can a take a few minutes for the process to occur so you might have a brief moment where the bucket doesn't have encryption.  I've updated the answer clarify the process.

Comment: yes that is correct and i appreciate it thanks you WaltDe